# Refresh same page in other controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a `<select>` to switch between languages in all footer pages, when user select a new language, I want to refresh the same page, not homepage.

To change language, `<select>` call to a `LanguageController` and this set `_locale` and redirect to correct controller to refresh the same page.

Which is the best way to refresh same page when user change language?

This is an example of my `config.yml`

```
homepage_es:
 path: /es
 defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Language:indexEs }
```

And this my `LanguageController`

```
 /**
 * @Route("/es", name="homepage_es")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexEsAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->set("_locale", 'es');
    return new RedirectResponse('/es/home');
}
```

Now Redirect to homepage, but I want to redirect to the same page where user was.

This is an `<option>` of my `<select>` in my `twig`

```
<option value="{{ path('homepage_es') }}">Español</option>
```

Comment: use the referer